# MySQL / PHP Drag and Drop File Upload

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, blobs

I am looking to upload files into a MySQL database using a drag and drop application.  Any ideas?

I want to be able to drag a file into the browser and then type in a file name.

THANKS!

Comment: +1 Welcome to Stack Overflow, Michael.

Answer (score 0):

The [Java Jump Loader](http://jumploader.com/demo_embedded.html) will allow you to drag files into your browser. Getting them referenced in a MySQL table will be a different job though. You'll have to run that query from the server-side.

The Jump Loader documentation even has [code examples demonstrating how to move the file once it's uploaded](http://jumploader.com/doc_serverside.html) to your permanent location. Inserting the file-reference into the database is a breeze from there.

Essentially, you'll just run an INSERT query containing the filepath:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO files(filepath) VALUES('%s')";
$rst = mysql_query( sprintf($sql, $filepath) ) or die( mysql_error() );
```

And if you need to you can spit out the newly created ID:

```
print mysql_insert_id();
```

For a demo of drag-and-drop uploading, visit http://jumploader.com/demo_embedded.html